# goa: how to set the wildcard in the routing path with payload

Tags: go, http

I'm using [goa.design](https://goa.design/design/types/) to implement my http interface. I have a `instanceID` type which is defined as

```golang
var InstanceID = Type("instance_id", Int, func() {
    Description("the id of an instance")
})
```

And I'd like to define a routing path taking the instance id as the parameter.

```golang
    Method("get_instance_metadata", func() {
        Payload(InstanceID)
        HTTP(func() {
            GET(fmt.Sprintf("%s/instance/{InstanceID}", BaseAPIPath))
        })
        Result(InstanceMetadata, "the metadata of an instance")
    })
```

However, when I try `goa gen`, it gives the following error:

```golang
exit status 1
route GET "/api/v1/instance/{InstanceID}" of service "myservice" HTTP endpoint "get_instance_metadata": Route param "InstanceID" not found in method payload
```

I did find a workaround, which is to define the `InstanceID` in this way:

```golang
var InstanceID = Type("instance_id", func() {
    Description("the id of an instance")
    Attribute("id", Int)
})
```

and define the method with

```golang
    Method("get_instance_metadata", func() {
        Payload(InstanceID)
        HTTP(func() {
            GET(fmt.Sprintf("%s/instance/{id}", BaseAPIPath))
        })
        Result(InstanceMetadata, "the metadata of an instance")
    })
```

However, this will create a cumbersome struct:

```golang
// the instance id
type InstanceID struct {
    ID *int
}
```

Eventually, all I want is just

```golang
type InstanceID int
```